# What is the measure of the set of sequences with convergent subsequences in the space of all real sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $S$ be the set of all unbounded (infinite) real sequences. What is the measure of: the subset $A=$ {sequences that have a convergent subsequence}?

I have a weak understanding of the concept of ”measure”, and there are many different types of “measure”, but I guess I’m referring to probability measure or Lebesgue measure? I’m not sure, but I’m hoping it doesn’t matter. I think I’m referring to the same type of measure that people mean when they say the rationals is measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$.

And I guess the answer is probably either $0$ or $1$ ? Hmm I think it is $1$. Because if I shoot countably many bullets at the real line (but with the holes (points) forming an unbounded set), it seems to me that it’s much more likely there will be a limit point than not. But maybe I am wrong

Comment: Lebesgue measure is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. This is the space of sequences. One has to define appropriate measure on it to talk about questions like above. Can I know what is it that you want to know about this particular set you are talking about? In other words, what do you mean by measure here?

Comment: So does the answer really depend on what type of measure you define?

Comment: Yes. And you need a measure on the space of sequences. A measure is simply a map from certain subsets of a set to the reals which obeys certain sensible notions, like if A is a subset of B, the measure of B should be greater than or equal to the measure of A. Strongly recommend you research measure before you proceed with questions like this.

Comment: Yes, it has to. For instance, with respect to counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$, the set of rationals have infinite measure.

Comment: I see. What if the measure was the/a probability measure? Is probability measure one type of measure, or are there different types of probability measure?

Comment: Probability measure is a measure with measure of whole space equal to 1. There are many measures like that.

Comment: It is not going to be $1$, even on $\mathbb{R}$ the Lebesgue measure of the whole space is infinite, it is not a probability measure. [Baker defined](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1991-113-04/S0002-9939-1991-1062827-X/) a "Lebesgue measure" on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, and your set is likely $0$ or $\infty$ if it is even measurable. To get a probability measure you should consider sequences bounded by some constant.

Comment: Alright, I guess I’ll have to re-visit this question if and when I learn more about measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

Baker defined a ["Lebesgue measure" on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1991-113-04/S0002-9939-1991-1062827-X/), the space of all real sequences which has the following characteristic property: the measure of infinite dimensional rectangle $a_i<x_i<b_i$ is the product $\Pi_i(b_i-a_i)$ when it converges.

Consider the set of all sequences bounded by a constant $|x_i|<M$. Since any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence it is contained in the OP set. Its Baker's measure is $\infty$ whenever $M>1/2$ because the partial products are $(2M)^n$ and grow without bound when $n\to\infty$. Since the OP set contains these sets for every $M$ its measure is also $\infty$. This should not be surprising. The condition that a sequence has a convergent subsequence does not impose any restrictions on any finite stretch of the sequence. And those stretches are enough to make the measure as large as one wants.